Why are ruby fibers instantaneous when I set my silly scheduler?
I'm trying to understand (and accomplish) "interweaving" concurrency using ruby Fibers. To do that - I tried to implement my own scheduler but I hit a roadblock.
Here's the code to test:
f1 = Fiber.new do
  puts "1: start"
  sleep 2
  puts "1: almost" 
  sleep 2
  puts "1: done"
end.resume

f2 = Fiber.new do
  puts "2: start"
  sleep 2
  puts "2: almost" 
  sleep 2
  puts "2: done"
end.resume

The theory is: without scheduler, the fibers are run sequentially, and the whole program takes 8s.
If I manage to implement a scheduler that can pass on control to another thread on IO (sleep in this case), the fibers should wait together, and the whole program should take ~4s.
So, I partially implemented my silly scheduler:
class S
  def initialize
    @fibers = []    
  end

  def block(blocker, timeout = nil) 
    fiber = Fiber.current
    puts "block", blocker.inspect, timeout.inspect, fiber.inspect
    @fibers << fiber
  end

  def unblock(blocker, fiber) 
    puts "unblock", blocker.inspect, fiber.inspect
    @fibers.reject!{ _1 == fiber} # remove the fiber
    fiber.resume
  end

  def fiber(&block)
    Fiber.new(blocking: false, &block).tap(&:resume)
  end

  def kernel_sleep(duration = nil) 
    @fibers << Fiber.current
  end

  def io_wait(io, events, timeout) 
    puts "io_wait not implemented"
  end
end

I added this part before my test fibers:
Fiber.set_scheduler(S.new) if ENV['SCHEDULER'] == 'yes'

And the results completely surprised me: The fibers are not sleeping at all!
time SCHEDULER=yes ruby fiber-non-blocking-io.rb
1: start
1: almost
1: done
2: start
2: almost
2: done
SCHEDULER=yes ruby fiber-non-blocking-io.rb  0.05s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 0.083 total

What is going on here? I clearly don't understand how the scheduler is supposed to work.
My mental model was something like this (let's focus on kernel_sleep/sleep for simplicity):

My fiber is resumed, outputs the first message, and hits sleep
scheduler's kernel_sleep is called, and I store it for later
2a. (I didn't get to implementing Fiber.yield to pass back the control)
At some point, I should iterate over my sleeping fibers and check if it's time to resume them, but I didn't get to that part.

(The fact that the puts in the scheduler's code is not showing up also does not help. Clearly, the scheduler does something because the behavior changed, but I can't see those outputs)

Ok, I think I managed to improve my understanding.

What is going on here?

One can (conceptually) think of kernel_sleep as an inline replacement of sleep() inside the Fiber. So if its implementation does not implement some other way to sleep, it will not do it.
Thanks for Max's answer (please give it an upvote)
So, a better implementation looks like this:
def kernel_sleep(duration = nil)
    wait_till = Time.now + duration
    fiber = Fiber.current
    debug "kernel_sleep(#{duration.inspect})", fiber.inspect

    # Store the fiber together with the timestamp when it should be resumed
    @sleeping << [fiber, wait_till]
    # pass control to other fibers (a.k.a pause it) 
    Fiber.yield
  end


I clearly don't understand how the scheduler is supposed to work.

So my block was the idea that the scheduler will somehow "circle back" later to all those paused fibers - it will not.
It's completely up to us to ensure all fibers were resumed enough times.
So, adding another method to the scheduler like this one:
def run
    while !@sleeping.empty? 
      ready_index = @sleeping.find_index { |_fiber, time| time <= Time.now }
      next unless ready_index 
      ready = @sleeping.delete_at(ready_index)[0]
      debug("resume #{ready}")
      ready.resume
    end
  end

And then calling it after the the sleeping fibers were resumed for the first time is the part that will make it work as expected:
Fiber.set_scheduler(S.new) if ENV['SCHEDULER'] == 'yes'

f1 = Fiber.new do
  debug "1: start"
  sleep 2
  debug "1: almost" 
  sleep 2
  debug "1: done"
end.resume

f2 = Fiber.new do
  debug "2: start"
  sleep 2
  debug "2: almost" 
  sleep 2
  debug "2: done"
end.resume

Fiber.scheduler.run

The whole program now runs for 4 seconds, and each fiber sleeps for total of 4 seconds:
time SCHEDULER=yes ruby fiber-non-blocking-io.rb
1: start
kernel_sleep(2)
#<Fiber:0x000078af88f5f590 fiber-non-blocking-io.rb:43 (resumed)>
2: start
kernel_sleep(2)
#<Fiber:0x000078af88f5ef00 fiber-non-blocking-io.rb:51 (resumed)>
resume #<Fiber:0x000078af88f5f590 fiber-non-blocking-io.rb:43 (suspended)>
1: almost
kernel_sleep(2)
#<Fiber:0x000078af88f5f590 fiber-non-blocking-io.rb:43 (resumed)>
resume #<Fiber:0x000078af88f5ef00 fiber-non-blocking-io.rb:51 (suspended)>
2: almost
kernel_sleep(2)
#<Fiber:0x000078af88f5ef00 fiber-non-blocking-io.rb:51 (resumed)>
resume #<Fiber:0x000078af88f5f590 fiber-non-blocking-io.rb:43 (suspended)>
1: done
resume #<Fiber:0x000078af88f5ef00 fiber-non-blocking-io.rb:51 (suspended)>
2: done
SCHEDULER=yes ruby fiber-non-blocking-io.rb  4.04s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 4.066 total

Here's the full (not really, it works only with sleep and no other blocking IO) example:
require 'fiber' 

def debug(...)
  # return unless ENV['DEBUG'] == 'yes'
  puts(...) 
end

class S
  def initialize
    @sleeping = []
  end

  # The following are requried by the interfacem but don't matter in this example
  def block(blocker, timeout = nil)= raise "Not implemented"
  def unblock(blocker, fiber)= raise "Not implemented"
  def fiber(&block)= Fiber.new(blocking: false, &block).tap(&:resume)

  def kernel_sleep(duration = nil)
    wait_till = Time.now + duration
    fiber = Fiber.current
    debug "kernel_sleep(#{duration.inspect})", fiber.inspect

    @sleeping << [fiber, wait_till]
    Fiber.yield
  end

  def io_wait(io, events, timeout) 
    raise "io_wait not implemented"
  end

  def run
    while !@sleeping.empty? 
      ready_index = @sleeping.find_index { |_fiber, time| time <= Time.now }
      next unless ready_index 
      ready = @sleeping.delete_at(ready_index)[0]
      debug("resume #{ready}")
      ready.resume
    end
  end
end

Fiber.set_scheduler(S.new) if ENV['SCHEDULER'] == 'yes'

f1 = Fiber.new do
  debug "1: start"
  sleep 2
  debug "1: almost" 
  sleep 2
  debug "1: done"
end.resume

f2 = Fiber.new do
  debug "2: start"
  sleep 2
  debug "2: almost" 
  sleep 2
  debug "2: done"
end.resume

Fiber.scheduler.run


Fiber expects you to implement the actual sleep delaying using something like an event loop. You can see something like this in a real scheduler like Async. When a fiber sleeps, it schedules a timer to resume the fiber at the appropriate later time.
Your implementation of a scheduler literally tells any sleeping fiber to keep running right now, which is what they're doing.
None of your other scheduler methods are being used. Try putting fail calls inside all of them (other than kernel_sleep) and you'll see they never get hit.

Ok, but how is this event loop is supposed to be started? Is this a part of FiberScheduler interface? None of the methods seem like a good candidate.

Thanks for mentioning Async - but this is not very helpful. Async is the reason I decided to write something on my own. It's hard to read and complex with schedulers, reactors and selectors (that are implemented in C, and are using platform specific mechanisms like EPoll for linux).
